# Countdown Timer should not restart when activity is refreshed.

Tags: android, native

I am designing an app(ABC) in which user is given a specific time to complete his task with in 3 hour. 
A Count Down Timer is shown to the user. But it works fine until the activity is in view as soon as he switches between apps(The app is still running in background) the countdown timer restarts. And shows both the time with some milliseconds difference. What i want to do is that the time should not refresh. It should continue it's countdown.

Here is the code that i have been using.

```
 private void mytimer()
{
    final int duration=3600000; //1 hours
    new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000)
    {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            long secondsInMilli = 1000;
            long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
            long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;

            long elapsedHours = millisUntilFinished / hoursInMilli;
            millisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished % hoursInMilli;

            long elapsedMinutes = millisUntilFinished / minutesInMilli;
            millisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished % minutesInMilli;

            long elapsedSeconds = millisUntilFinished / secondsInMilli;

            String yy = String.format("%02d:%02d",elapsedMinutes,elapsedSeconds);
            R_Time.setText("Remaining Time:"+yy);
        }

        public void onFinish()
        {

            R_Time.setText("Time Finished");
            AlertDialogUtils.showInfo(getContext(),R.string.time_finished__info);

        }

    }.start();
}
```

Comment: just save the elapsed time in sharedPreferences or somewhere and restart your countdown timer again with total time -  elapsed time.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps,

1. Save the device time in DB/preference/file when task starts
2. Start your timer

Lets assume, your app restarts. Here you need to start `CountDownTimer` for X mins only as step #3.

3. Start timer for X mins = Total time limit for user - (Stored Time - Current Time)

Answer (score 0):

Create a service with counDownTimer and keep on notify to broadcast receive. Register broadcast receiver inside main activity. this way you can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BroadcastService extends Service {

private final static String TAG = "BroadcastService";

public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "your_package_name.countdown_br";
Intent brod_intent = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);

CountDownTimer count_down = null;

@Override
    public void onCreate() {       
        super.onCreate();

        count_down = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                brod_intent.putExtra("countstart", millisUntilFinished);
                sendBroadcast(brod_intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
            }
        };

        count_down.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        count_down.cancel();
        Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelled");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {       
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {       
        return null;
    }
}
```

From your activity start service

```
 startService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
```

Also you need to define service on manifest file.

Comment: watch out for calling `startService` when targeting Android 8.0 because: `The startService() method now throws an IllegalStateException if an app targeting Android 8.0 tries to use that method in a situation when it isn't permitted to create background services.`

Comment: how to get time in TextView? How to set broadcast? Can you please write it for me. Broadcast is new for me